# Why str.encode('ascii') doesn't work for this case?

Tags: python, unicode

```
In [1]: str='美'

In [2]: str.encode('utf-8')
Out[2]: b'\xe7\xbe\x8e'

In [3]: str.encode('utf-16')
Out[3]: b'\xff\xfe\x8e\x7f'

In [4]: str.encode('ascii')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/XXXuserXXXTemp/<ipython-input-4-c7b96e3e54a7> in <module>()
----> 1 str.encode('ascii')

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u7f8e' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The `str` is a Chinese/Japanese character.

- why `ascii` does not work?
- how to understand Out[2] and Out[3], i.e. what they really are?

Comment: I don't see an `Out[1]`. Do you mean "how to understand Out[2] and Out[3]"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why `ascii` does not work?

`str='美'` is not an ASCII character, it's outside the ASCII range and therefore can't be represented as an ASCII character.

From the [Unicode tutorial for python](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html):

> Encodings don’t have to handle every possible Unicode character, and most encodings don’t. For example, Python’s default encoding is the ‘ascii’ encoding. The rules for converting a Unicode string into the ASCII encoding are simple; for each code point:
>
> 1. If the code point is < 128, each byte is the same as the value of the code point.
> 2. **If the code point is 128 or greater, the Unicode string can’t be represented in this encoding. (Python raises a UnicodeEncodeError exception in this case.)**

---

> how to understand `Out[2]` and `Out[3]`, i.e. what they really are?

They are byte strings (not character strings). `Out[2]` is the sequence of bytes which represents the `美` codepoint in UTF-8 code units. The notation `\xe7` means a byte with the hexadecimal value e7. `Out[3]` is the sequence of bytes which represents the `美` codepoint in UTF-16 code units.

To understand the distinction between characters, bytes, and code units, read the [*Unicode tutorial for python*](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) carefully and completely. For another, fairly good, treatment of the same material, read Joel Spolsky's [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). You should know this much, no excuses!

Comment: What does "each byte is the same as the value of the code point" mean? Could you illustrate it with an example?

Comment: In "escaped forms", what is escaped?  "Unicode value sequence" is still somewhat undefined. What is it really?

Answer (score 4):

- [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) contains no hanzi/kanji, therefore there is no valid way to encode it.
- They are [encoded text](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 2):

As the error states you supplied a non ascii character and tried to encode it to ascii. Won't work, it has to be an ascii character to encode it to ascii. If you want to find the ascii characters you can look here.

http://www.asciitable.com/

Basically only the basic characters in ascii are the english alphabet and some punctuation/special characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can't encode that character to `ascii` because it's not part of the characters that can be represented with `ascii`.

`Out[2]` and `Out[3]` are the binary representation of your character in utf-8 and utf-16.